# C++ client and Java Server message

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP/IP Socket program, client program is written in c++. The server program is written in Java. The message sent from the client to the server socket is a sequence of a byte, an integer and an IP address. To decrease the size of the message I wanted to send only bytes and receive only bytes and then do the conversion on the server side. No separators between diff values.

1. To do this what code should be executed on the client side to convert all these values into byte array to be sent?
2. If we were to send the int as is from c++ what would I get on the server side?
3. How exactly will an ip address be sent and recieved?

I am aware that if I know before hand the number of bytes in a datatype( for example int is 4 bytes in c++.), in my server I can use the ByteBuffer to convert the coming 4 bytes array to an int.

Please let me know if anyone has a basic solution to this. Thanks,

**EDITED**
So i write something like this to convert say int to byte array in the C++ client::

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<unsigned char> intToBytes(int paramInt)
{
     vector<unsigned char> arrayOfByte(4);
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         arrayOfByte[3 - i] = (paramInt >> (i * 8));
     return arrayOfByte;
}
```

and in Java Server I use ByteBuffer to convert back.
Is this the right way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decide on exactly what bytes will be sent and then code both sides to the decision. If the integer must be, say, in the range of 0 to 30,000, then you could decide to use two bytes with the high byte first. You can pick anything you want, just code it appropriately on both sides.

Comment: true, Thats what I want to do. But how would the c++ client send an int as bytes?

Comment: However you want. You can decide. You can say "it will be three bytes, from low order to high order". Or whatever meets the requirements of the protocol.

Comment: That's the idea. But don't start with the code. Start with a protocol specification on paper describing, at the byte level, what information will be exchanged. Then implement that protocol on both ends. Trust me, it's worth the extra effort to document the protocol.

Comment: yes that is ready, but as the conversions are not clear i needed to confirm the process. Thanks